# Some files still remain in $RECYCLE.BIN

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, recycle-bin

I ran a scan with SpaceSniffer and WinDirStat and noticed that there are over 11 gigs of files stored in $RECYCLE.BIN and when I open it, all the folders inside show 0 bytes. My recycle bin is empty and I've run CCleaner just now. What may be the cause of this, is it safe to try and delete those files?

Also, I have reinstalled windows a couple times in the past if that needs mentioning.

[image]
[image]

Comment: It appears you have multiple users, since you have, multiple recycle bins.  Evident by the 3 GB, 600 MB, also listed.  The particular bin your asking about is on an second partition other then the system partition (default location).  CCleaner should not be trusted.  Additionally, look up the S-1-5 number, to identify if it’s a built-in user or not.

Comment: I only have 1 user, could those files be from the past installs of windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The folders you are seeing are from other users. It is possible they were carried over from previous installs, and its possible you had profile issues, and they are old versions of your current profile.

In either case, if you do not want the files, its safe to delete them.

You can right-click these folders and choose open in exploror to explore the content of these folders and delete as you see fit.

Comment: Explorer probably needs to be run as administrator.

Comment: I have deleted those folders within WinDirStat, everything ok, hope didn't do anything wrong. Freed up 11 gigs of storage.

Comment: @harrymc WinDirStat will handle that for you popping up an UAC dialog.

Answer (score 2):

Try to delete the Recycle Bin folder with these following commands as administrator. Let assume the drive letter is `K:`. Here are the steps:

1. Take ownership: `Takeown /F "K:\$RECYCLE.BIN" /R /D Y`
2. Change permission: `Icacls "K:\$RECYCLE.BIN" /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)(F) /T`
3. Remove system attributes: `Attrib -R -S -H "K:\$RECYCLE.BIN" /S /D`
4. Delete folder: `Rmdir /S /Q "K:\$RECYCLE.BIN"`

Alternatively, combine those steps in a single batch file (.bat) and run it as administrator:

```bat
@echo off
Takeown /F "K:\$RECYCLE.BIN" /R /D Y 
Icacls "K:\$RECYCLE.BIN" /grant Everyone:(OI)(CI)(F) /T 
Attrib -R -S -H "K:\$RECYCLE.BIN" /S /D 
Rmdir /S /Q "K:\$RECYCLE.BIN" 
pause
```

Then restart Explorer or log-out and re-login into your account.

### Further details:

- [Takeown command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/takeown)
- [Icacls command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/icacls)
- [Attrib command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/attrib)
- [Rmdir command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/rmdir)